# imported modules with window access in Cypress tests

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, cypress

I'm writing some cypress tests for a library I'm developing, It is meant to be injected as `<script src="cdn_url"></script>` and I want to test some of its features, so I'm testing the modules, but I'm having problems with getting the window object from my module.

I have a module that does:

```
var domCheck = setInterval(myFunction, 2000);

function myFunction() {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete' && window.mktData) {
    clearInterval(domCheck);
    console.log(window.data)
  }
}
```

so I created a fake index.html that will work as my test page.

In my test I do:

```
const data = require('../fixtures/data'); -- a json with some data
import { myFunction } from '../../src/index';

describe('My function test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    Cypress.Cookies.debug(true);
    cy.visit('../cypress/fixtures/index.html');
    cy.clearCookies();
  })

  it('My test', () => {
    cy.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
      Object.defineProperty(win, 'data', data)
    })

    myFunction;
    expect(true).to.equal(true)
  })
})
```

When I execute the test myFunction gets executed but window.data is undefined. I get that cypress runs in a different context, but I don't know how to make myFunction run in the same context and being able to have access to window.data

I also tried adding `<script> window.data = { value: myValue } </script>` to my index.html test page but didn't work, so I understand that myFunction is running in a different context.

Can you please help me on how to make that module work in the same context as my test suite?

Comment: The main thing that's wrong is you are visiting the page before setting the `before:load` event listener. Move the `cy.on()` to before the `cy.visit()`.

Comment: Thanks Ackroydd, I also tried that, but my window object is still undefined

Comment: Actually, the Cypress `window:before:load` *does* work. Your problem is around `myFunction` which at least needs to be self executing.

Comment: Importing `myFunction` into the test and trying to execute it there will not test it via the `index.html`. The call to `myFunction()` in the test is looking at a different window, that of the test runner, not the iframe containing the `index.html` page.

Comment: Hey! Still struggling with this, I edited my question to add more detail to how my main func works. I'm wondering If I just should create a task to compile my module and then add it to my html somehow (actually don't know how to do that) but that would be more accurate to real functionality. Thanks!

Comment: Hey soni, as mentioned `cy.on('window:before:load')` is in the wrong place. And don't do `Object.defineProperty(win, 'data', data)`, do `win.data = data;`